# On using the loss as a metric?

Tags: model-evaluation, supervised-learning, metric, loss-functions

The context is model evaluation in supervised learning. I am coming from a numerical optimisation background. For me it is quite natural to use the loss of the model (what we optimise during training) as an evaluation metric.

However it seems that it is not a common practice and Data Scientists use all sort of metrics, often quite far from the original loss.

On top of that, standard loss (MSE / log-loss) have all sort of good properties (typically being derivable, being a proper scoring rule for binary classification... etc.). So it is especially not clear what is gained from choosing something else.

So I am wondering if there is any reliable source on the pro and cons of using/not using the original loss as a metric?

Answer (score 3):

It is not too uncommon to have the raw loss as an observed metric. That said, here's some reasons to consider alternative metrics:

1. Loss function is not easily interpreted/compared. For example, with standard logistic loss in binary outcomes, we know that lower is better...but we don't really know how much improvement we can expect from our model if the logistic loss reduced from 1e5 to 1e4. On the other hand, with AUC ROC, we know that 0.5 = completely random model, 1.0 = perfect prediction model and we can interpret AUC ROC as $P(\hat y_1 > \hat y_2 | y_1 = 1, y_2 = 0)$. Sure it's not the easiest metric to interpret but easier than logistic loss. That said, AUC ROC itself would be a really silly metric to optimize (invariant under positive linear transformations of $\hat y$ for example), so it may make sense as an evaluation metric but not an optimization objective.
2. Sanity check for over-optimization of the loss function. Your optimization function should optimize its target function...but sometimes optimizing the loss function can unexpectedly create very odd solutions. If we see our target function (say mean squared error) steadily decreasing, but what we believe to be a highly correlated metric (say median absolute error) start to increase, our model is probably doing something very weird that we didn't intend. Disclaimer: not a high recall sanity check.
3. Evaluation metric is better aligned with end goal but makes for a very difficult optimization problem. For example, in recommender systems, we really care that our top $k$ recommendations are good matches for a user (since this is what we'll be showing them), but don't care so much about further down the tail since they won't be shown anyways. So [precision/recall at k](https://www.shaped.ai/blog/evaluating-recommendation-systems-part-1) is a common evaluation metric for recommender systems, but it would a nightmarishly difficult target function to optimize directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I was mostly looking for a guidelines that generally justify using the loss as a metric. Currently I am often faced with cases were the loss is skipped entirely instead of using another metric on top of the loss.

Comment: @LucasMorin: I can't see a strong argument for not monitoring the loss, especially splitting training and eval to determine if overfitting is kicking in. In some rare situations that I've worked on, it's actually more computationally expensive to evaluate the loss than it is improve it, but that is extremely rare. Other than that case, I don't think there's a stronger argument to not monitor than "I don't really care that much about the loss compared to other metrics and I don't want to look at too many plots".